# Multinomial logistic regression vs. Dirichlet regression

Tags: regression, logistic, dirichlet-distribution

I am looking for a tool to carry out regressions on probability vectors given a continuous variable as input (or covariate in statistics words). Typically, this can be done through [multinomial logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) where the inputs are $x^{(i)} \in \Re^{n}$, and where given a test input $x$, we want our hypothesis to estimate the probability that $P(y = k | x)$ for each value of $k = 1, \ldots, K$.

I was wondering if a more compelling approach would be to use [Dirichlet regression](http://epub.wu.ac.at/4077/) where (broadly speaking) the Dirichlet distribution concentration parameters $\alpha_i$ are a function of the input variable $x$, and the output is the distribution support $y_1, \ldots, y_K$ where $y_j \in (0,1)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^Ky_j=1$. The "flaw" I can see when using Dirichlet regression is that none of my output variables can have a value of zero or one, in contrast to the multinomial logistic regression.

Any advice here? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Those are two different models for different data. Does your data consists only from 0s and 1s, or is it continuous in (0,1). Answering this question would lead you to answer what model do you need to use.

Comment: Well, my inputs (covariates) are real vectors, while my output is a probability vector, that is, its entries are between [0,1] and their sum is always 1. In this case, which model should I use?

Comment: Dirichlet regression.

Comment: @Tim I think that depends more on the nature of said probability: if it's actually a fraction of "successes" (therefore binomial and by extension multinomial logistic regression fits the bill) or a continuous probability.